# "ERROR: OpenGLES initialization failed!" on CentOS with android SKD

Tags: android

When I run: 
    `/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd tst`

I get the error:

```
Failed to open lib64EGL_translator
Failed to init_egl_dispatch
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES initialization failed!
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation library could not be initialized!
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

I've followed the steps here: http://www.redips.net/android/emulator-fedora-linux/

I've also tried using the commands emulator-arm and emulator64-arm

Another thing I tried was

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Another attempt was with the parameters:

```
-no-audio -gpu off
```

I'm using a fresh install of CentOS 6.6 with yum update ran.  I'm using the android SDK: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-linux.tgz

I ran /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/android and installed the Android 5.0 api+arm.  I tried again with a Android 4.4 AVM.

I've tried all the suggestions I could find.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi Brian, the folder /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib doesn't exist on my computer. What packages do I need to install?

Answer (score 2):

Before running the emulator from the command line add the **`lib64`** directory to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, e.g.:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

or

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

dependently on the SDK installation path.

Answer (score 0):

My reply is meant to "second" brian's post, so it is known brian is not the only one seeing this error.

On my CentOS 6.6 box I have also tried the same steps listed and I am also seeing *nearly* the same error messages.  The only difference is I do not get:

```
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

My emulator *does* run with just basic invocation (this AVD is not configured to use the host's GPU):

```
emulator -avd Nexus_S_ARM
```

But the error messages indicate something is broken and should be put right.

Answer (score 0):

The 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' made it workd for me. Also specfied '-gpu off' in the command line.